# how to download instrument classification model h5 (hdf5) file

Tags: hdf5, librosa, hdf

I want to recognize most of the instruments (at least 6 types) from a music flac/mp3 file and I need a model and it's filename like 'instrument_classification_model.h5' (for python libROSA or MIRaGE).
I have tried to search and find it but failed, Does anyone know the download URL, another alternative file or another method to recognize ?

```
# import
import librosa
import librosa.feature
import librosa.util
import librosa.core

# load file and transform to number
audio_path = 'music.wav'
audio, sr = librosa.load(audio_path)

# get mfcc
mfcc = librosa.feature.mfcc(audio, sr=sr)

# load model
model = librosa.util.load_hdf5('instrument_classification_model.h5')
# ...
```